# Unable to localize multi robot due to amcl not receiving scan data

Tags: slam, amcl, laserscan, ros-noetic, multi-robot

Hello guys i am working on multi robot. All works well. I am able to get topics for different robot for their namespaces . I am also able to echo the scan topics , provide the map by the map-server node and also visualize laser scan topic for the different robot. But the thing is that the message below keeps coming up which can't allow me to localize my robots on the map . Can anyone kindly help me out . I will really appreciate.

```
[ WARN] [1694984020.672553324, 113.209000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 113.209000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /robot1/scan topic.
```

Also screenshot below:

[image]

RVIZ:

[image]